# Position FlexSlider navigation bar at center properly

Tags: css, wordpress, gallery, flexslider

I working on small project, and have an weird issue that cant resolve myself. I have a flex slider gallery, that is shown images into ribbon bellow main center image. But for some reason, it shown the ribbon not center positioned, and left and right pointers dont work. This is code for that element:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="gallery-single-post clearfix">
                                <div class="clearfix" id="slider">
                                    <?php inspiry_list_custom_gallery_images('gallery-post-single'); ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php
                                $size_thumb = 'gallery-post-single-thumb';
                                $gallery_images = rwmb_meta('MEDICAL_META_custom_gallery', 'type=plupload_image&size=' . $size_thumb, $post->ID);
                                if (!empty($gallery_images)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                                        <ul class="slides">
                                            <?php
                                            foreach ($gallery_images as $gallery_image) {
                                                $caption = (!empty($gallery_image['caption'])) ? $gallery_image['caption'] : $gallery_image['alt'];
                                                echo '<li>';
                                                echo '<img src="' . $gallery_image['url'] . '" alt="' . $gallery_image['title'] . '" />';
                                                echo '</li>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and this is CSS for that element:

```
.gallery-single #carousel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto 33px;
  padding: 0 48px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
 }
```

**[This](http://spas-hammam.com/wp/gallery-item/kids-treatment/) is now looks currently**:

[image]

and t[his](https://echographie-sans-frontieres.com/staging/gallery-item/divers/) (user/password is login) is **how need to look**:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Did you try adding other picture to see how it looks?

Answer (score 1):

To Center the ribbon remove the margin left and right, it's already absolute so you can use left by 50% and then transform to adjust the left position

```
.gallery-single #carousel {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -35px;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 48px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: After inserting this CSS, i dont see changes to visual look. See http://spas-hammam.com/wp/gallery-item/kids-treatment/

Comment: Also seems like left and right arrows next to flexslider not working at all.. Buttons are present, but not working when press it.. Any tip how to resolve this?

Comment: when I try to get to you link it gives me "AUTHENTICATION REQUIRED You need a username and password to access this area."

Comment: for the buttons I need to debug js to find the issue could you put your slider on a codepen or something so I could find the error ?

Comment: have writen that into post.